# I want to add a comment to a for loop in `algorithm`

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

```
\begin{algorithm}[h]
   \caption{Transformation}
   \tcp{Apply transformation X comment1}
   \For{$k=1$ \KwTo $n$} 
   {$P=A*P*A^{T}$ \tcp{comment 2}}
\end{algorithm}
```

I want to add a comment in for loop line.

Comment: Do you mean a comment in the source code (using `%` ), or a comment, readable in the Latex-output?

Comment: comment readable in the Latex output...

Comment: \For{$k=1$ \KwTo $n$} \\ this is for loop

Comment: want to comment in this way

Comment: Hm, a good starting point is to provide complete minimal code, i.e. which can be copied and run right away. The fragment simply can't, for obvious reasons. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The first answer forces the `do` into the next line. This solution here doesn't:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[h]
       \caption{Transformation}
       \tcp{Apply transformation X comment1}
       \For(\tcp*[f]{this is for loop}){$k=1$ \KwTo $n$} 
        {$P=A*P*A^{T}$ \tcp{comment 2}}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1):

Just place one of the comment macros inside the `\For{}`-part:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}[h]
       \caption{Transformation}
       \tcp{Apply transformation X comment1}
       \For{$k=1$ \KwTo $n$ \tcp{this is for loop}} 
        {$P=A*P*A^{T}$ \tcp{comment 2}}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See chapter 10.3 in https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf for alternatives.

Comment: Thank you it solve my problem. Is this same applicable when I used \usepackage{algorithm} and \usepackage{algorithmic}. I am finding errors when I used this packages

Comment: The manuals of those packages should tell you, if and how comments are provided. You may also check the "Related" column to the right, search here or search the tags.